# Google Chrome broke (or changed behavior) of a focus on window.opener window?

Tags: google-chrome

Case.

1. I open a **new window** from **main window** (by window.open).
2. I have focus on input on **main window** and I type something.
3. Something happens on a new window (Websocket send event, for example).

And now *(current version of Google Chrome 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit), Ubuntu 16.04, but it can be repeat on Windows, though)* Chrome switch focus from whole main window to the "child window". I didn't change code couple months, but on previous version of Chrome the focus of **main window** wasn't stolen by **new window**.

Is it norm?

Comment: Alright, I've found solution for only my problem: a *new window* had a focus() method on a constructor of that window. On new Chrome version it executes even if the global focus is on the main window. 
Strange, but okay. Need to check the logs of updates Chrome more closely.